# Is the C in the CAP theorem the same as the I in ACID?

Tags: database, eventual-consistency

[This article](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html) states that:

> Consistency in CAP actually means linearizability, which is a very
>   specific (and very strong) notion of consistency. In particular it has
>   got nothing to do with the C in ACID

The article goes on to define linearizability with:

> If operation B started after operation A successfully completed, then
>   operation B must see the the system in the same state as it was on
>   completion of operation A, or a newer state.

To me, this is very similar to the definition of [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation):

> The isolation property ensures that the concurrent execution of
>   transactions results in a system state that would be obtained if
>   transactions were executed sequentially, i.e., one after the other.

Is there any difference between the I (isolation) in ACID and the C (consistency) in CAP?

Comment: You make the claim that the C for Consistency in CAP has nothing to do with the C in ACID yet don't define the C in ACID to support that claim. Instead you only make claim that the C in CAP means linearizability. So when you say "between the two" It's not clear what you mean because you just talked about 3 different things. Please edit to support your claims. Do this with quotes, not simply links. And make clear which two things you want to know the difference between.

Comment: @CandiedOrange "Do this with quotes, not simply links". I posted **3** quotes.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Would you please explain why those don't count, and then, given that those that I base my question on don't count, what type of quotes would "support my claims" (I didn't claim anything, I stated what the article and Wikipedia say).